How to add padding to an object in a SceneKit in Swift
So I am trying to make something in SceneKit, but whatever I do it always takes up the whole size of the container it is in. I would like to change that, by maybe adding a little padding all around, or being able to dynamically change the size of it. For testing purposes, I am using a circle to test it, but it always seems to conform to the size of the SceneKit.
here is the SceneKit that I created:
struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let imageName: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let sceneView = SCNView()
        sceneView.scene = makeScene()
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return sceneView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        // No dynamic updates needed yet
    }

    private func makeScene() -> SCNScene {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let badgeNode = createBadgeNode(from: imageName)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(badgeNode)

        return scene
    }

    private func createBadgeNode(from imageName: String) -> SCNNode {
        guard let image = UIImage(named: imageName) else {
            fatalError("Image \(imageName) not found in assets.")
        }

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 40 // <-- seems to do nothing
        let maxBadgeWidth = screenWidth - horizontalPadding
        let aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height

        let badgeWidth = Float(min(maxBadgeWidth, screenHeight * aspectRatio)) / 1000
        let badgeHeight = badgeWidth / Float(aspectRatio)

        let badgeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(badgeWidth), height: CGFloat(badgeHeight))
        let badgeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        badgeMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
        badgeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
        badgeGeometry.materials = [badgeMaterial]

        let badgeNode = SCNNode(geometry: badgeGeometry)
        badgeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)

        return badgeNode
    }
}

And here is the contentView, I just have these two views:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SceneKitView(imageName: "Test1")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

I have tried to adjust the values in the createBadgeNode function, but if I tried to change the value in the badgeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(badgeWidth), height: CGFloat(badgeHeight)) it only seems to affect the height of the object in the SceneKit. If I try and change it in both of them it changes the shape too much. I will provide examples:
Normal (what appears in above function):


let badgeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(badgeWidth) + 0.1, height: CGFloat(badgeHeight))
        let badgeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        badgeMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
        badgeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
        badgeGeometry.materials = [badgeMaterial]


let badgeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(badgeWidth) + 0.1, height: CGFloat(badgeHeight) + 0.1)
        let badgeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        badgeMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
        badgeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
        badgeGeometry.materials = [badgeMaterial]


let badgeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(badgeWidth) + 0.1, height: CGFloat(badgeHeight) + 0.5)
        let badgeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        badgeMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
        badgeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
        badgeGeometry.materials = [badgeMaterial]


If there is anything that I can answer, please ask.

could you share your project for download?

#ZAY is there a reason. All the code in the project is above. the only thing that is the circle is an image I made in Figma in the shape of a circle

It would be easier to debug, if I have the real project, instead of creating a fresh one.

I can't get into my GitHub account at this time. Sorry. I am working on it, it is just taking time.
